# Routing different users to same EC2 behind ELB in sticky sessions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

We're evaluating different architectural approaches so do not have AWS to play with. Essentially we're trying to work out if it's possible to route multiple users to the same EC2 instance behind one ELB with sticky sessions.

[One bit of documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/US_StickySessions.html#US_EnableStickySessionsAppCookies) says "The load balancer uses a special cookie to associate the session with the original server that handled the request, but follows the lifetime of the application-generated cookie corresponding to the cookie name specified in the policy configuration. The load balancer only inserts a new stickiness cookie if the application response includes a new application cookie. The load balancer stickiness cookie does not update with each request. If the application cookie is explicitly removed or expires, the session stops being sticky until a new application cookie is issued."

[Another bit says](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/APIReference/API_CreateAppCookieStickinessPolicy.html) "An application client must receive and send two cookies: the application-generated cookie and the special Elastic Load Balancing cookie named AWSELB. This is the default behavior for many common web browsers."

Does this mean that if every user who wants to share a session set their "my-cookie" to the same value, they would always be routed to the same EC2?

Also, as a bonus question - can sticky sessions lead to DDoS potential on the EC2 traffic is forwarded to?

Comment: In theory, what you say should work. To better help you, could you explain what you're trying to achieve with this approach? Also, you can take advantage of the Free Usage Tier to test your approach (it includes EC2 t2.micro and Load Balancer).

Comment: We've already used up the free tier service, although I could sign up with a different email address. An end user will be able to process files, but we want those files to stick around, so they need to either be sent back to the original ec2 processor, or we need to look further into EBS / HDFS.

Comment: If you want to retain files and/or have them accessible to multiple servers, Amazon S3 is probably a better repository to use.

Comment: Not for temp files. These files need accessing hundreds of times in a given session. S3 is entirely wrong for us!

Comment: I am also looking for the same solution for a multiplayer game. Were you able to find a solution?  @cazgp